# Need to add to a counter while the next row is larger/smaller

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub HMM()
Dim x As Integer

Dim GG As Integer
Dim Gr As Integer
Dim rG As Integer
Dim rr As Integer

For x = 3 To x = 26126
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 3) > 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 1, 3) > 0 Then
            GG = GG + 1
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 3) > 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 1, 3) < 0 Then
            Gr = Gr + 1
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 3) < 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 1, 3) > 0 Then
            rG = rG + 1
    End If
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 3) < 0 And ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 1, 3) < 0 Then
            rr = rr + 1
    End if
 Next x

 With ActiveSheet
   .Cells(2, 30) = GG
   .Cells(3, 30) = Gr
   .Cells(4, 30) = rG
   .Cells(5, 30) = rr
End With

End Sub
```

So i have a long list of numbers ranging from C3 to C26126. What I need to do is find out how many times a positive number precedes a positive number (GG), how many times a negative number precedes a positive number (rG), etc. So I need GG Gr rG and rr. Sorry if this isn't clear enough.

Example: I have a table y: [-1,2,2,3,-1,-2,2] GG = 2, Gr = 1, rG = 2, rr = 1

My ultimate goal is to find a simple hidden markov model for my time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim pp, pn, np, nn, x, arr, v1, v2

    arr = ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C1110").Value
    For x = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) - 1
        v1 = arr(x, 1): v2 = arr(x + 1, 1)
        If v1 > 0 And v2 > 0 Then
            pp = pp + 1
        ElseIf v1 > 0 And v2 < 0 Then
            pn = pn + 1
        ElseIf v1 < 0 And v2 > 0 Then
            np = np + 1
        ElseIf v1 < 0 And v2 < 0 Then
            nn = nn + 1
        End If
    Next x

    Debug.Print pp, pn, np, nn

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what the question is .... since you've already given an answer

```
Sub HMM()
    Dim myWS As Worksheet
    Set myWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim x As Integer

    Dim GG As Integer
    Dim Gr As Integer
    Dim rG As Integer
    Dim rr As Integer

    'Initially 0 by default but it's always good to be explicit
    GG = 0
    Gr = 0
    rG = 0
    rr = 0

    'Count from 3 to 26125 instead of from 3 to 26126
    With myWS
        For x = 3 To 26125

            If .Cells(x, 3).Value > 0 Then
                If .Cells(x + 1, 3).Value > 0 Then
                    GG = GG + 1
                ElseIf .Cells(x + 1, 3).Value < 0 Then
                    Gr = Gr + 1
                End If
            ElseIf .Cells(x, 3).Value < 0 Then
                If .Cells(x + 1, 3).Value > 0 Then
                    rG = rG + 1
                ElseIf .Cells(x + 1, 3).Value < 0 Then
                    rr = rr + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next x

        Debug.Print GG, Gr, rG, rr

    End With

End Sub
```

If I were you, I would set .Cells(x+1,3) to a variable and then compare.. But I was not sure which variable type I should use since there is a limit to everything..